# How to allow linkify url to allow <x x> after a valid url in chat message

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a linkify url text which is in chat message which O needs to allow even `<x x>` after a valid url. Now when I am using any string after url, it ends up with

> InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on
> 'Document': The tag name provided ('x<') is not a valid name.

This should allow

1. before & after strings Ex: Hi this is test page https://www.test.com as well

**Code**

```
sendUrlText(e) {
    if (e && e.keyCode && e.keyCode !== 13) return;
    var stateMessage = unescape(this.state.message);

    function linkify(stateMessage){
        return stateMessage.replace(/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>")
    }
    var formattedMessage = linkify(stateMessage); 
}
```

Any suggestion how can I allow `/< x x >` after url and turns it into
For example:
[image]

with a linkify url.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve] so we can see how you pass `<x x>` as state message

Comment: Please post the HTML of the expected result instead of as an image - and if <x x> is an example, please post a relevant example

Comment: Please post a relevant example. We cannot GUESS that `https://www.test.com/<x x>` needs to be `<a href="https://www.test.com/>https://www.test.com/</a>`<x x>

Comment: @mplungjan My bad. sorry

Comment: So the answer is: We CANNOT extract a URL from text where there is no puntuation or whitespace AFTER the URL. We can extract from `This is a link: https://www.test.com/ in a sentence` but not `This is a link: -->https://www.test.com/<-- see the link`

Comment: My current regex is working fine for other cases like extracting test before or after the link . I have the issue that i cannot able to post it with `<a href="https://www.test.com/>https://www.test.com/</a><x x>` .

Comment: Your first script is getting me that `<a href="https://www.test.com/>https://www.test.com/</a><x x>` but it i not extracting the urls from texts. So in my case it should work with `hiii this is test <a href="https://www.test.com/>https://www.test.com/</a><x x> have a look`

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```js
function linkify(stateMessage) {
  const string = stateMessage.match(/(https?:\/\/[^ ]*)/);
  if (!string) return ""
  const url = new URL(string[1])  
  return  stateMessage.replace(string[1],`<a href='${url.toString()}' target='_blank'>${url.toString()}</a>`)
}

const link = linkify('Hello, this is a link https://www.test.com/ with a space and valid text') 
console.log(link)
document.getElementById("urlOutput").innerHTML = link;
```

```html
<span id="urlOutput"></span>
```

Comment: Hi mplungjan thank you for your time but i just want to display as it is like
https://www.test.com/<x x> without <x x> to be linked

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Have a look at updated code. You need in comments to post links in `\`` backticks for me to see what you mean

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: your first answer is working for me but its failing when I am using with 
Ex: `hii this is https://www.test.com` .
This comes with error of  `TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL`

Comment: See update to second script which will ignore the pathname from the string passed

Comment: I updated the answer according to what I understand

Comment: I just try with this . It almost get me there .
`hii https://www.test.com/%3Cx x>` in text message. I want this to be `hii https://www.test.com/<x x>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230221/discussion-between-tammy-and-mplungjan).